# I have a problem when I tried to upload multiple files in node.js using multer

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, multer

I'm trying to build a service that allows me to upload files I started with single-file uploading but I have an issue when I try to upload multiple files.

In short, my problem is that if I want to upload more than one image, it appears in the **storage** folder and I don't see the records in my DB.

**Example of single-file upload record**

[image]

**Example of multi-file upload record**

[image]

**But those files are saved on my storage**

[image]

Comment: please share some code which you have tired. so it will be easy to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two function in multer:

For single file to upload use:

```
upload.single('avatar')
```

For multiple file to upload use:

```
upload.array('photos', 12) //here 12 is max number of files to upload.
```

Refer to the following sample code:

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const app = express();
const multerStorage = multer.memoryStorage();
// Filter files with multer if you need
const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image")) {
cb(null, true);
} else {
cb("upload only images.", false);
}
};
const upload = multer({
storage: multerStorage,
fileFilter: multerFilter,
});
app.post('/singleUpload', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res,
next) {
// req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
console.log(req.file);//req.file is the `avatar` file. here avatar is
input field name
})
app.post('/multipleUpload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req,
res, next) {
// req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
// req.files is array of `photos` files.here avatar is
input field name
console.log(req.files);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay.
and my problem shown in the 1st picture in my question look at it and see my problem

Comment: In the first picture, I tried to add multiple files.
In the second picture, I added a single file and it worked.